# Is there a standard metric for sorted text?

Tags: text, metrics

Given a range of numbers, say from [80,240], it is easy to determine how much of that range lies within [100,105]: (105-100)/(240-80) = 5/160 = .03125. Easy.

So now, how much of a Meriam Webster dictionary lies between umbrella and velvet? Even if we assume uniform distribution of text across the corpus, is there a standard metric for text?

Comment: "how much of a Meriam Webster dictionary lies between umbrella and velvet" -- some number of lemmata that you can count, and divide by the total number to normalize it.

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether to use an index to access the underlying data. Hence I do not know how many words are in this range without actually accessing them. Assuming uniform distribution of words, how many can I estimate to lie between umbrella and velvet? Let's say I know that there are 1,000,000 words in the total dictionary (a made up number of course).

Comment: You can't know because of the lexicographic ordering. You'll have to fetch all the words, sort them and apply your formula to their indices.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard for that. If you had all entries from Meriam Webster in an array, you could use first and last positions as the bounds, so you would have a set going from 1 to n. Then you could pick the positions of "umbrella" and "velvet", call them `x` and `y`, and calculate your range as `(y - x + 1) / (n)`.

That works if you are seeing words as elements of an ordered set, so as to have them behave as real numbers. You are basically dividing the distance between two numbers in a set by the distance between the boundaries of the set. Some forms of algebra deal with them differently - when calculating the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between any two given words, for example, each words is seen as a vector with as many dimensions as they have characters.

You could define the boundaries of your n-dimensional space by using the biggest word in Meriam Webster (hint: it's "pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", so your space would have 45 dimensions). However, when considering any `A-B` pair of words, a third word `C` of intermediary length may or may not be between those, depending on the operations involved in the transformation from `A` to `B`.

You'd have to check every word with a length between that of `A` and `B` to check whether they are part of the range between `A` and `B`... So it's not a matter of simple calculus, and I don't know if this could be even feasible with a regular computer nowadays. And that's just considering Meriam's close to half a million entries.

Comment: I'm familiar with Levenshtein, along with a few others (Jaro, Hamming, and such). I'm wondering more about estimating the position of a word within an alphabetically ordered/sorted list of words. Assume that the larger corpus is uniformly distributed.

Comment: Well, you'll have to know the positions of those words, and the amount of words/position of the last word, then. So you can use the formula you provided in your question.